# owncloud webDAV access

Tags: debian, webdav

I have been trying to mount my owncloud server to my debian (stable with backports) system following the tutorial on owncloud website the command line part.

http://doc.owncloud.org/server/6.0/user_manual/files/files.html

Everything goes well but when I try to `mount ~/owncloud/` then even thought I have created the correct secret file in .davfs2 I'm requested to enter username and password. The volume is then mounted but I cant copy any files in it.

Any Ideas?

Thanks.